# INNER JOIN sql with Seperate Property

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables

**Table Languages**

[image]

**Table Versions**

[image]

In both tables, id is the primary key

The language_id in versions table is Foreign Key to Languages Table.

I am running a Inner Join and below is my query.

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'versions';
$languages_table = $wpdb->prefix.'languages';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name INNER JOIN $languages_table ON $table_name.language_id = $languages_table.id";
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

***Actual Ouptupt***

This outputs

```
    {
        "success": true,
        "data": {
            "rows": [
                {
                    "id": "40",
                    "abbreviation": "kjv",
                    "name": "English",
                    "language_id": "40",
                    "code": "en",
                    "native_name": "English"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

The id and name of versions table are overridden by languages id and name. I understand the table column should be defined as with unique column names.

***Expected Ouptupt***

Can I get an output from sql with seperate property as shown below.

```
    {
        "success": true,
        "data": {
            "rows": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "abbreviation": "kjv",
                    "name":"Kings James Vesion",
                    "language_id": "40",
                    "language": {
                        "id":"40",
                        "name": "English",
                        "code": "en",
                        "native_name": "English"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Or should I run a loop individually and get for each row.

Comment: You have columns with the same name, and hence they cannot be distinguished by the name. You MUST replace an asterisk in `SELECT *` with definite table.column names, and assign unique aliases to each column with duplicated name.

Answer (score 1):

I will get rid of "SELECT *". Besides this problem, it could introduce bugs when you change the table structure later. You can format the data in your code when it's really need.